# Import video as round plane

Tags: image, video

new here so hope someone can help and new to Blender also. I am trying to import video to play on a circular plane instead of square, what is the best way to make plane circular?

Comment: do you mean that the video will be deformed or it's just that the screen will be circular? in the second case just create a circle and give it an Image Texture with your video uploaded?

Comment: Just circular, I will try that thanks

Answer (score 0):

delete your plane.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> -> Mesh -> Circle -> <kbd>Tab</kbd> (edit mode) -> <kbd>F</kbd> -> Circular plane

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

1.Press Shift + A > Mesh > Circle

2. From the little menu that appears on the bottom left, set the fill mode to n-gon
3. Go to shading tab
4. Create a new material
5. Set the material to glossy bsdf and set the roughness to 0 and white colour
6. create a camera
7. Press numpad 7 to go to top view.
8. Press F3 and select align camera to view
9. Set renderer to cycles
10. Press Shift + A > Images > Images as planes
11. In the menu that opens, select the video file and set the material to emit.
12. Move the plane above the camera
13. Go to camera view.
14. Scale the image you added up so that it is reflected on the circle
15. Press Play.
16. For step-by-step instruction watch the video(I swear it's not a  rick roll).

Video - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fiMW-o_DmIcP5S6v5aJCGn13ux5Z1xH8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it looks like you rickrolled us, lol  ;)